# Angular material theme stays default

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

No matter what i do the H1 color stay white and without background color,
Here is my code:

```
<div ng-app="TestApplication">
    <md-toolbar>
        <h1 class="md-primary">Hello world</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApplication', ['ngMaterial']);
app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('red')
    .accentPalette('yellow');
});
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/WrZLvJ)

I'm Using :
**Angular** - V1.4.8
**Angular material** - V1.0.2

Thanks you very much guys

Comment: So do you want to change the toolbar color or have a box around the h1?

Comment: I edited your post to include the sample code and a codepen. Pastebin is not very helpful, try to provide a minimal example that people can play around with. Now please refine your question because I don't exactly understand what you expect of the sample to be different.

Comment: Thanks you guys, i success doing this, i still don't know what the problem was i just reopened the project and its works.

Answer (score 0):

You can only define the theme for directive. In case if you want to override the child element color use CSS.

```css
h1{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="TestApplication" ng-cloak>
  <md-toolbar class="md-accent">
    <h1> Hello world </h1>
  </md-toolbar>
</div>
```